# Web Development Tools for ASP.NET Core RC2 in vs2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-core-rc2

How to add this `Templates` to `vs2015`?

my Templates :

[image]

.NET Core Templates :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of mid-May 2016, you can now install the latest ASP .NET RC2 release from:

- https://www.microsoft.com/net/core

From previous documentation and  blog posts, you may have seen this URL:

- http://get.asp.net

This "get" URL just redirects to the new .NET page under Microsoft.com, where you can click the Blue "Download .NET Core" button that goes to the first link I shared above.

Also, check out the following blog post and comments below it, to get some guidance on uninstalling what you already have installed.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2

Hope that helps!

Comment: The .NET Core SDK does not include the Templates, you need the Web Development Tools for that, which you can download from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798481)

Comment: During the VS2015 install, you should see a checkbox to include the web development tools. Thanks for adding the direct link to the Microsoft download, @Negorath! :)